# Simple JS timer using JS Fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery

This may not be the place for this question, but here goes anyways.

I am trying to learn more about the JS timers and am using the JS Fiddle for this purpose. In my script, I am using a script that binds functionality to a few elements, but I need the JS Fiddle to not execute it until the page loads completely due to it needing all elements to be initialized and available (see my fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/radi8/W2b2M/4/). This fiddle is a VERY rough skeleton.

The format of the script is as follows:
How can I make the JS Fiddle only load this after all other elements are finished?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var tmr = {
      init: function(){
      },
      somefunct1: function(){
      },
      somefunction2: function(){
      }
    };tmr.init();
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.ready() is the way to good.  However, there are other issues with your code.  This function is not defined correctly:

```
function stopTimer {
  clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Should be:

```
function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Also, startstop.value is not defined.  What is startstop suppose to be?

**Update**

Your use of .val() is incorrect, and many other issues (fixed):

http://jsfiddle.net/W2b2M/17/

Comment: Reload with the http://jsfiddle.net/radi8/W2b2M/8/ fiddle. It would appear that I forgot to save the last edits I did (novice mistake, sorry).

Comment: Well, ok then. Thanks for the help. I will get this stuff right eventually.

Comment: Utilizing the Firebug (in Firefox), or other F-12 dev tools in Chrome, Safari, and IE9 really help out.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Fiddle:

A simple Javascript Function to Set timer.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var input = 120;

    function calculateTime(timer) {
        var timer = timer;
        var mins = Math.floor(timer / 60);
        var secs = timer % 60;
        var time = (mins < 10 ? "0" : "") + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "") + secs;
        return time;
    };

    setInterval(function () {
        data = calculateTime(input)
        if (input > 0)
        {
            $("#timer").text(data);
            input--;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#timer").text("Time Out, Njoy Coding in JavaScript")
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MUMU1987/sUkjj/